# Finding objects without relationship in django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, and want to retrieve all objects that **DON'T** have a relationship to the current object I am looking at.

The idea is a simple Twitter copycat.

I am trying to figure out how to implement `get_non_followers`.

```
from django.db import models


RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
                         (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
                         (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
)



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', 
                                           symmetrical=False, 
                                           related_name='related_to')
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
    
    def add_relationship(self, person, status):
        relationship, created = Relationship.objects.get_or_create(
            from_person=self,
            to_person=person,
            status=status)
        return relationship
    
    def remove_relationship(self, person, status):
        Relationship.objects.filter(
            from_person=self, 
            to_person=person,
            status=status).delete()
        return
       

    def get_relationships(self, status):
        return self.relationships.filter(
        to_people__status=status, 
        to_people__from_person=self)
        
    
    def get_related_to(self, status):
        return self.related_to.filter(
            from_people__status=status, 
            from_people__to_person=self)
    
    def get_following(self):
        return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)
    
    def get_followers(self):
        return self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_non_followers(self):
        # How to do this?
        return


class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)
```

Comment: What is the non_follower definition? Everybody that don't has a RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING relationship or just from UserProfile.relationships?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly glamorous, but it gives correct results (just tested):

```
def get_non_followers(self):
    UserProfile.objects.exclude(to_people=self,
        to_people__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING).exclude(id=self.id)
```

In short, use `exclude()` to filter out all `UserProfiles` following the current user, which will leave the user themselves (who probably shouldn't be included) and all users not following them.

Comment: Thanks, it was almost what I was looking for. A small change I had to do:

return UserProfile.objects.exclude(to_person__from_person=self, to_person__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING).exclude(id=self.id)

(add __from_person to to_person) , as it wasn't filtering users that the current user is already following.

Comment: @Avi "wasn't filtering users that the current user is already following"? I think you've got `get_non_followers` and `get_non_following` backwards; surely it doesn't mattter which users the current user is following — shouldn't `get_non_followers` return users **not following the current user**?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I needed get_non_following, and asked for get_non_followers.. Sorry about that.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right. So can you either edit your question to what you actually wanted (so I can edit my answer) or accept mine as-is? Editing my solution into your question without attribution isn't particularly community-spirited, particularly when your odd situation (why on earth are you setting `related_name` on a through model, for instance) meant I had to create a whole test project to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the implementation of `get_non_followers`:

```
def get_non_following(self):
    return UserProfile.objects.exclude(to_person__from_person=self, to_person__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING).exclude(id=self.id)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12009792/2) to the question [Finding objects without relationship in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009792/finding-objects-without-relationship-in-django) by the OP [Avi Meir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607447/avi-meir) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

```
current_userprofile = current_user.get_profile()
rest_of_users = Set(UserProfile.objects.filter(user != current_userprofile))
follow_relationships = current_userprofile.relationships.filter(from_person=current_user)
followers = Set();
for follow in follow_relationships:
    followers.add(follow.to_person)

non_followeres = rest_of_users.difference(followers)
```

Here `non_followers` is the list of userprofiles you desire. `current_user` is the `user` whose `non_followers` you are trying to find.

Comment: -1 Typos, mistaken assumption that `current_user.get_profile()` will work (it almost certainly won't; `UserProfile` has no FK to `User`) — where does `current_user` come from anyway? Even if this idea is sound (and the 3 SQL queries to get 1 user list is not filling me with confidence), it's in an unusable state right now.

Comment: Its not meant for you to copy paste as is but more as a reference. You can get your user whatever way you want to!

Comment: & the mistakes? (*e.g.* `non_followeres`) & the fact that this isn't implemented as a model method? & the syntax error (`.filter(user != anything)` is completely wrong; queries are implemented using keyword arguments). & the fact that you're building a list of *every user* in the application, *every time* you run this?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this out, but it think it should do what you want.

```
def get_non_followers(self):
    return self.related_to.exclude(
    from_people__to_person=self)
```

Answer (score -1):

i'v been searching for a method or some way to do that for like an hour, but i found nothing.
but there is a way to do that. 
you can simply use a for loop to iterate through all objects and just remove all objects that they have a special attribute value. 
there is a sample code here:

```
all_objects = className.objects.all()
for obj in all_objects:
    if obj.some_attribute == "some_value":
        all_objects.remove(obj)
```